# Sample size in 2 x 2 x 2 mixed experimental design

Tags: anova, descriptive-statistics, ordinal-data, likert

I'm currently doing my university thesis, and I am unsure what sample size is required in order to achieve an acceptable statistical power. I have recruited them online, via posts on forums and FaceBook. The groups will therefore probably not be even. I currently have 108 participants, though I am unsure who falls into which group because I have not yet conducted analyses.  I know that there's a way of working out the desired amount of participants but I can't work it out. I will explain the design...

It is a 2 x 2 x 2 mixed experimental design.  I'm looking at student attitudes towards offenders. Participants are required to rate a number of statements on a Likert scale and an overall score is generated. The factors are study type (criminological vs. non-criminological); study level (undergraduate vs. post-graduate); and exposure to a case study (all participants will see the case study and the scores from before and after this will be compared). So there is one repeated measure - before and after reading the case study; and two independent measures; study type and study level.

I'm planning on conducting an ANOVA to measure the difference in attitudes towards offenders in relation to study type (those studying offenders vs. those  studying otherwise) and study level (undergraduate vs. post-graduate). Within-subjects t-tests will be also be used to determine significant differences within each factor.  I am not sure whether this is enough/correct.

I'm not very good at statistics and it's boggling my mind and I only have a month to complete it.

Comment: It's a good question, but "recruited ... randomly online" seems like a contradiction in terms. Could you share with us how you accomplished the randomization?

Comment: Sorry - I posted the link to the survey onto online forums/FaceBook and whoever wanted to complete it, did.  So therefore I had no control over which group each participant fell into and little control over how many there are in each group

Comment: "attitude" doesn't seem to be normally distributed. Usually, such psychological measurements are assessed by some score which is only ordinal. ANOVA and t-tests are only for continuous and metric data. So you have to enter the realm of nonparametric statistics, where the Wilcoxon test resides.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned how attitude is measured - participants rate a number of statements and an overall score is worked out.  Each participants' score will be compared before and after viewing the case study.

Comment: Since there was no randomization--even worse, almost no control at all over who responded--your options for making valid inferences or predictions are essentially nil. You can still run all the ANOVA machinery if you like, as an educational exercise, but the conclusions you might draw from the results would have no support. No hypothesis tests or confidence intervals, for instance, could produce justifiable results. Because of this, power studies and sample size determinations are pointless.

Comment: Even though I specified that only undergraduate/postgraduate students were required? And even though each participant specified which course and at which level they studied? That's annoying. What should I have done instead?